# sqlite3 database is locked(using bottle)

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I'm trying to use Bottle framework in python with sqlite3. Then I made a Todo List application but when I tried to post a data at the first time the error happened differently from above. The second time 'database is locked' happened.

Can anyone help?

```
#_*_ coding:utf-8- _*_

import os, sqlite3
from bottle import route, run, get, post, request, template

#sqlite from here----------------
dbname = "todo.db"
connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
dbcontrol = connection.cursor()

#Making table from here--------------------

create_table = '''create table todo_list (todo text)'''

@route("/")
def index():
    todo_list = get_todo()
    return template("index", todo_list=todo_list)
```

I think I need more specific code here.

```
@route("/enter", method=["POST"])
 def enter():
 conn = sqlite3.connect("todo.db")
 todo=request.POST.getunicode("todo_list")
 save_todo(todo)
 return redirect("/")




def save_todo(todo):
 connection = sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
 dbcontrol = connection.cursor()
 insert="insert into todo_list(todo) values('{0}')".format(todo)
 dbcontrol.execute(insert)
 connection.commit()

def get_todo():
 connection=sqlite3.connect('todo.db')
 dbcontrol = connection.cursor()
 select = "select * from todo_list"
 dbcontrol.execute(select)
 row = dbcontrol.fetchall()
 return row

run(host="localhost", port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix the indetation of your code and post [minimal, complete, and verifyable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem.

Comment: The problem is that there are multiple connection/cursor objects active at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [bottle-sqlite](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle-sqlite) with:

```
$ pip install bottle-sqlite
```

An example from the plugin

```
import bottle

app = bottle.Bottle()
plugin = bottle.ext.sqlite.Plugin(dbfile='/tmp/test.db')
app.install(plugin)

@app.route('/show/:item')
def show(item, db):
    row = db.execute('SELECT * from items where name=?', item).fetchone()
    if row:
        return template('showitem', page=row)
    return HTTPError(404, "Page not found")
```

Important notes from the plugin

> Routes that do not expect a db keyword argument are not affected.
>
> The connection handle is configured so that sqlite3.Row objects can be
> accessed both by index (like tuples) and case-insensitively by name.
> At the end of the request cycle, outstanding transactions are
> committed and the connection is closed automatically. If an error
> occurs, any changes to the database since the last commit are rolled
> back to keep the database in a consistent state.

Also take a look at **[Configuration](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle-sqlite#configuration)** section.